# Convert list of maps into map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and programming and I am wondering how to go about solving this problem.

I have derived the below list of maps

```
({:name "Bob",
  :occupation "Senior salesman",
  :work-department "Sales"}
 {:name "Sharon",
  :occupation "Executive",
  :work-department "Sales"}
 {:name "Donald",
  :occupation "Customer Support agent",
  :work-department "Client services"}
 {:name "Catherine",
  :occupation "Technical Lead", 
  :work-department "Engineering"})
```

How would I go about turning this from a list of maps to a map of the following style?

```
{:sales
 {:name "Bob"
  :occupation "Senior salesman"}
 :sales
 {:name "Sharon"
  :occupation "Executive"}
 :client-services
 {:name "Donald"
  :occupation "Customer Support agent"}
 :engineering
 {:name "Catherine"
  :occupation "Technical Lead"}}
```

Thanking you for the help

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Right now your desired result shows a map with an odd number of elements, which is impossible. If you want to break out two of the key/vals into their own map, that map itself will also need a key. E.g. `{:work-dept "xxx" :employee {:name "xxx" :occupation "xxx"}}`  Please update your question to show the full and exact output you want for the sample input (no xxx's :-)

Comment: Thank you  for kindly responding. I have amended my question with the requested information

Comment: Now there is two times `:sales` in the map. If you expect help, please also take the time to focus on the problem and try your code examples first, so they don't contain obvious errors

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I will strive to improve on my questions and quality. 
On the note of the two times :sales - is there way to cater for cases such when the data will contain the same value?

Comment: Thanks all for this feedback.

Thank you to Alan Thompson as well for the books. Im using the youtube to learn so it is sort of touch an go,

Answer (score 2):

You might find the group-by function useful in this situation. Say we define your list of maps as "before"

```
> before
({:name "Bob",
  :occupation "Senior salesman",
  :work-department "Sales"}
 {:name "Sharon", :occupation "Executive", :work-department "Sales"}
 {:name "Donald",
  :occupation "Customer Support agent",
  :work-department "Client services"}
 {:name "Catherine",
  :occupation "Technical Lead",
  :work-department "Engineering"})
```

Then group-by will produce a map from key to a list of items with that key:

```
> (group-by :work-department before)

{"Sales"
 [{:name "Bob",
   :occupation "Senior salesman",
   :work-department "Sales"}
  {:name "Sharon",
   :occupation "Executive",
   :work-department "Sales"}],
 "Client services"
 [{:name "Donald",
   :occupation "Customer Support agent",
   :work-department "Client services"}],
 "Engineering"
 [{:name "Catherine",
   :occupation "Technical Lead",
   :work-department "Engineering"}]}
```

If you'd rather have a flat structure output, you could just transform each entry like this:

```
> (map (fn [e] [(:work-department e) (dissoc e :work-department)]) before)

(["Sales" {:name "Bob", :occupation "Senior salesman"}]
 ["Sales" {:name "Sharon", :occupation "Executive"}]
 ["Client services"
  {:name "Donald", :occupation "Customer Support agent"}]
 ["Engineering" {:name "Catherine", :occupation "Technical Lead"}])
```

Comment: Thanks Markc! This is wonderful

I am really appreciating the help on this one